# sqlalchemy backref without name but cascade

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

We have a User class for people registered to the system. And we have a load of classes (and plugins add more) belonging to a user. So if a user is deleted, his things should be deleted.
So here is, what we're doing currently:

```
class User(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
class Thing(Base):
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(User.id))
    user = relationship(
        User,
        backref=backref("list_of_things",
            cascade="all, delete-orphan"))
```

This works.

Assume we never use `User.list_of_things`: Is there a way to leave it out? But still get the backref cascade behaviour? If we ever need `User.list_of_things`, we can add it, of course. But until then, it would be nice to leave it out.

You could say "Well, just put a name in and don't care". That's what we're doing. Two things:

1. We will need to define a naming convention just for that thing, so that names from plugins wont conflict on the `User` class with other plugins and/or our main attributes there.
2. Would make things easier to read/write.

Small update: An *untested* solution to our problem at hand would be a mixin on the lines of, but it would not answer the question of backrefs without names:

```
class OwnedbyUserMixin(object):
    @declared_attr
    def user_id(cls):
        return Column(Integer, ForeignKey(User.id),
            nullable=False)

    @declared_attr
    def user(cls):
        return relationship(
            User,
            backref=backref("list_of_" + cls.__tablename__,
                cascade="all, delete-orphan"))
```

Comment: This is a very interesting question. Did you find a solution?

Comment: nope. If I ever hear of one, I'll answer my own question here.

Comment: in the meantime, I think the best approach is to have different models depending on what is to be done with them: in complex models with 100+ tables there are probably a couple of orthogonal use cases. Just define your models only for the use case, leave the rest out. Have a deletion model. You'll find a reduced memory footprint for each application and less brain hemorrhaging when changing code as a bonus.